# Absolute difference between time.Duration

Tags: go, time

I have 2 variables with `time.Duration` type. I need to find the difference in duration between them.

For example:

- v1 = 1sec and v2 = 10sec — difference is 9 sec.
- v1 = 10sec and v2 = 1sec — difference is also 9 sec.

Both variables can have different values for hours, minutes etc.

**How can I do this in Go?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Go 1.19

The function [`Abs`](https://pkg.go.dev/time@master#Duration.Abs) has been added to the language, so you can just use that instead of rolling your own:

```
func main() {
    d1 := time.Second * 10
    d2 := time.Second

    sub1 := d1 - d2
    sub2 := d2 - d1

    fmt.Println(sub1.Abs()) // 9s
    fmt.Println(sub2.Abs()) // 9s
}
```

Comment: Switched accepted answer to this since it makes no sense to implement hand made alternative now.

Answer (score 3):

Package time provides `Abs` functionality since Go1.19:

```
// Abs returns the absolute value of d.
// As a special case, math.MinInt64 is converted to math.MaxInt64.
func (d Duration) Abs() Duration {
    switch {
    case d >= 0:
        return d
    case d == minDuration:
        return maxDuration
    default:
        return -d
    }
}
```

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    a := 1 * time.Second
    b := 10 * time.Second
    c := (a - b).Abs()
    fmt.Println(c) // 9s
}
```

---

Try this (without using new `Abs()` from time package):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    a := 1 * time.Second
    b := 10 * time.Second
    c := absDiff(a, b)
    fmt.Println(c)         // 9s
    fmt.Println(absDiff(b, a)) // 9s

}
func absDiff(a, b time.Duration) time.Duration {
    if a >= b {
        return a - b
    }
    return b - a
}
```

---

This is another form:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    a := 1 * time.Second
    b := 10 * time.Second
    c := abs(a - b)
    fmt.Println(c) // 9s
}

func abs(a time.Duration) time.Duration {
    if a >= 0 {
        return a
    }
    return -a
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there native Abs function for Duration in Go?

Comment: Not, like this, You may use `c := time.Duration(math.Abs(float64(a - b)))`, but it uses unnecessary floating point operation.

Comment: I would use a modified version of your answer. Abs can have if diff < 0 { diff = -diff }. This will be a real Abs without substriction that doesn't relate to it

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution is to use bitshift >>

```golang
func absDuration(d time.Duration) time.Duration {
   s := d >> 63 
   return (d ^ s) - s
}
```

bitshift in Golang is logic if the left operand is negative

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).